# How to remove items in list based on poja class values

Tags: java, list

How to remove the list items from list like below

```
List<Mypojaclass> results = new ArrayList<>();
      // in the results i am adding more items using sql query, after that,
        if(Mypojaclass sensor : results){
            if(sensor.getType.equals("JD"){
             sensor.remove(sensor);
             }
        }
```

I can do it using iterator if its like below,

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (Iterator<String> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    String a = iter.next();
    if (...) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

But i should remove the items based on that sensor.getType only.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Side note on code quality: your code snippet implies that you have a function that is supposed to collect a list of objects as "results" List. And then your method starts making changes to another data structure? If it is like that: dont do that (unless your method is actually something like collectFooAndUpdateBar or something alike). What I am saying is: collecting something and updating something else ... is something that doesn't belong into the same place.

Comment: @MMMMS do you want to remove all occurrence when getType equals "JD" or just the first occurrence?

Comment: Your question itself has answer. Using Iterator you can get POJO and remove it if type equals JD.

Comment: @Faraz Durrani I want to remove the current list where that JD get match. If there are 5 list then if the JD match in list(3) then it should remove list(3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Java 8 you can do this:

```
results = results.stream().filter(p ->! p.getType().equals("JD")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For Java 7 and below the safest bet would be:

```
Iterator<Mypojaclass> itr = results.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
   Mypojaclass item = itr.next();
   if("JD".equals(item.getType())){
      itr.remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your Java 8 example does filter the list in the reverse way, it only contains elements with getType == JD

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose would this be better? results.stream().filter(p -> !p.getType().equals("JD")).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

Comment: cf 'Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Chapter 5, Item 23 : Don't use raw types in new code'

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I did not get the reference to raw types. What part was that directed at?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose great catch, was so focussed on the Java 8 version that totally missed this.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to give an answer because the others seem to struggle with the lists, iterators, streams, and so on.

**First, the problem:**

A code snippet like this

```
List<Mypojaclass> results = ...;
for (Mypojaclass sensor : results) {
    if (sensor.getType.equals("JD") {
        results.remove(sensor); // <-- possible CME here
     }
}
```

is buggy because it simply can throw a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). The reason is that the for-each-loop uses an iterator, so the above code is equivalent to the following code that uses an explicit iterator:

```
List<Mypojaclass> results = ...;
for (Iterator<Mypojaclass> itr = result.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    Mypojaclass sensor = itr.next();
    if (sensor.getType.equals("JD") {
        results.remove(sensor);
     }
}
```

Note, that you call `remove` on the list, not on the iterator. The iterator then throws the CME because the list was changed *outside* the iterator.

**The solution:**

Call the `remove` operation on the iterator:

```
List<Mypojaclass> results = ...;
for (Iterator<Mypojaclass> itr = result.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    Mypojaclass sensor = itr.next();
    if (sensor.getType.equals("JD") {
        itr.remove();
     }
}
```

Now this code snippet iterates once through the whole list while simultaneously removing all occurrences of sensors whose type equals to "JD".

**Java 8 code:**

As we are now in the Java 8 time aera, this will do the same in Java 8:

```
results.removeIf(s -> s.getType().equals("JD"));
```

Or - with the help of a stream and some filtering:

```
List<Mypojaclass> filtered = results
        .stream()
        .filter(s -> !s.getType().equals("JD"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
results = filtered;
```

Note here, that the filter predicate has to be negated. You don't want to have the "JD" types. You want to have all the other types.

Comment: Thank you. nice explanation

Answer (score 2):

For Java 8:

```
results.removeIf(f -> f.getType().equals("JD"));
```

Removes all items from the list having a type of "JD"

For plain Java 7:

```
List<Mypojaclass> filteredResults = new ArrayList<>();
for (Mypojaclass item: results) {
    if (!item.getType().equals("JD")) {
        filteredResults.add(item);
    }
}
```

Alternative

```
Iterator<Mypojaclass> iterator = results.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Mypojaclass item = iterator.next();
    if (item.getType().equals("JD")) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Now filtered Results contains the filtered list.
In case of Java 7 you could also think about using commons-collections which contains methods to achieve those filtering mechanism.

```
results.stream().filter(p -> p.getType().equals("JD"));
```

from the above comment does nothing. You would need to collect the items in a new list and you would have to negate the filter predicate because otherwise you would end up with a collection with just elements that have a type of "JD"

Comment: I would add it's even better if you check that `"JD".equals(f.getType())` to prevent NPEs. Alternatively you could use `Objects.equals(f.getType(), "JD")` ! Of course it totally depends on your context and if you are doing the check in a "safe zone"

Comment: @LouisF. It would not totally prevent NPEs. `f` could also be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the neatest but I think it works

```
List<Mypojaclass> results = new ArrayList<Mypojaclass>();
Mypojaclass [] placeHolder = null;  //this will hold the object(s) to be removed
int length = 0;                     //this will hold the length of this new array of placeHolder array
for (Mypojaclass sensor : results) {
  if(sensor.getType.equals("JD"){
    length++;
  }
}

placeHolder = new Mypojaclass[length]; //allocates memory 

for (Mypojaclass sensor : results){
  if(sensor.getType.equals("JD"){
    placeHolder[length-1] = sensor;      //initialize 
    length--;
  }
}

//This will remove all instances when getType equals "JD"
for(int i = 0; i < placeHolder.length; i++){
  results.remove(placeHolder[i]);
}
```

Comment: That will remove only the last instance with type `JD`.

Comment: `placeholder` is reassigned each time the loop encounters an element with type `"JD"`. The last such encountered will be removed. If you want to remove the first, you need to `break` the loop.

Comment: Although it seems technically correct (didn't evaluate it), I would not recommend that approach. Creating a temporary array is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Please, dont take a downvote personally. See it as it is meant: A possibility to improve. A downvote simply reminds you that either the answer is wrong or not good at all. It obviously takes some time to write good answers. Good answers are answers that are not technically correct, but also explain some of the circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a for loop:

```
List<Mypojaclass> results = new ArrayList<>();
// in the results i am adding more items using sql query, after that,
for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    if(results.get(i).getType.equals("JD"){
        results.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Or just use the Iterator directly:

```
List<Mypojaclass> results = new ArrayList<>();
// in the results i am adding more items using sql query, after that,
Iterator<Mypojaclass> iterator = results.iterator()
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    if(iterator.next().getType().equals("JD"){
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```